# Cancelling any additional participants when primary cancels

Tags: civievent

We have a closed registration scenario for CiviEvents where 'members' can register guests but have to be in attendance themselves. However, as it currently stands it appears that if you allow cancellations when the 'member' cancels their registration any additional participants they have registered remain. Is there a way to ensure that when a primary registrant cancels all their registrations get cancelled too?